# Error Converting .docx to Html using Java Docx4J library

Tags: java, spring, docx4j

class org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.BinaryPart cannot be cast to class org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.ObfuscatedFontPart (org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.BinaryPart and org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.ObfuscatedFontPart are in unnamed module of loader 'app'

```
public String saveFile( RequestDTO saveRequest) throws Docx4JException, IOException {

    var payload=saveRequest.getDocFile();
     PipedOutputStream osPipe = new PipedOutputStream();
     PipedInputStream isPipe = new PipedInputStream(osPipe);
     DataBufferUtils.write(payload.content(), osPipe)
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
             .doOnComplete(() -> {
                 try {
                     osPipe.close();
                 } catch (IOException ignored) {
                 }
             })
             .subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer());
     byte[] bytes = isPipe.readAllBytes();
   ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
         var doc =  WordprocessingMLPackage.load(byteArrayInputStream);
         var updater = new FieldUpdater(doc);
         updater.update(true);


     HTMLSettings htmlSettings = Docx4J.createHTMLSettings();
         File images = new File("/image/");
         File baseUri = new File("");
         htmlSettings.setImageDirPath(images.getAbsolutePath());
         htmlSettings.setImageTargetUri(baseUri.getAbsolutePath());
         htmlSettings.setWmlPackage(doc);
         var mapper =htmlSettings.getFontMapper();
      Docx4jProperties.setProperty("docx4j.Convert.Out.HTML.OutputMethodXML", true);
         ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          Docx4J.toHTML(htmlSettings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
         var str = new String(os.toByteArray());
        os.close();
         if (doc.getMainDocumentPart().getFontTablePart() != null) {
             doc.getMainDocumentPart().getFontTablePart()
                     .deleteEmbeddedFontTempFiles();
         }

return  str;


 }
```

I am expecting the html to be returned as string. It working fine with most of document but give exception with the document I need to convert.

Comment: Your paste of the exception message is missing the front part that says it's a ClassCastException. Here's a [google query for the exception message](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+%22are+in+unnamed+module+of+loader%22&oq=java+%22are+in+unnamed+module+of+loader%22). The code you have showed doesn't seem to include the classes involved in the cast. Please inspect your full stack trace to try to locate the code doing that cast and share that code.

Comment: Also see the instructions for creating an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You have not provided inputs (the file) that reproduce the issue or instructions on how to create such an input file. (Also- I forgot to say- welcome to SO!)

Comment: Yes, sample input XHTML please.